# VSCode crashing on opening despite completely fresh install

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode just crashes on opening with the 'Window terminated unexpectantly...' message as if it is trying to open a previously opened file.

Tried running in safe mode but still crashing even after deleting VScode and ensuring no leftover folders/appdata/backups/extensions etc before restarting PC and installing again.

Tried both user and system installs (my pc is set to run as administrator).

This is the result with the current system install :

C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code>Code.exe/safemode

C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code>
[main 2023-08-29T12:56:40.222Z] update#setState idle
[main 2023-08-29T12:56:45.432Z] CodeWindow: renderer process gone (reason: crashed, code: -1073741818)
Error sending from webFrameMain:  Error: Render frame was disposed before WebFrameMain could be accessed
at s.send (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:86306)
at _.send (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:71895)
at E.send (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:19:96025)
at P.p (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:23:4460)
at P.o (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:23:4425)
at P.m (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:23:4291)
at o.value (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:24:258)
at b.w (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:18:1906)
at b.fire (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:18:2123)
at o.value (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:16:38875)
at b.w (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:18:1906)
at b.fire (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:18:2123)
at o.value (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:16:38681)
at b.w (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:18:1906)
at b.fire (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:18:2123)
at S.deregisterLogger (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:42:6325)
at S.deregisterLogger (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:42:50793)
at S.deregisterLoggers (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:42:51452)
at kt.dispose (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:89:4626)
at BrowserWindow. (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:88:97429)
at BrowserWindow.emit (node:events:525:35)
at kt.kb (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:88:100296)
at kt.jb (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:88:100069)
Error sending from webFrameMain:  Error: Render frame was disposed before WebFrameMain could be accessed
at s.send (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:86306)
at _.send (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:71895)
at E.send (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:19:96025)
at P.p (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:23:4460)
at P.o (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:23:4425)
at P.m (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:23:4291)
at o.value (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:24:258)
at b.w (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:18:1906)
at b.fire (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:18:2123)
at o.value (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:16:38875)
at b.w (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:18:1906)
at b.fire (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:18:2123)
at o.value (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:16:38681)
at b.w (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:18:1906)
at b.fire (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:18:2123)
at S.deregisterLogger (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:42:6325)
at S.deregisterLogger (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:42:50793)
at S.deregisterLoggers (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:42:51452)
at kt.dispose (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:89:4626)
at BrowserWindow. (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:88:97429)
at BrowserWindow.emit (node:events:525:35)
at kt.kb (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:88:100296)
at kt.jb (C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-main\main.js:88:100069)

Can anyone help me as I have no idea what is going wrong or how to fix. VScode was working fine until the latest update but I don't think I can go back to the earlier version now.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Native-Crash-Issues#creating-and-symbolicating-local-crash-reports. if you raise an issue ticket following those instructions, please ping me with a link to it. I looked through https://www.google.com/search?q=github+vscode+issues+%22Error%3A+Render+frame+was+disposed+before+WebFrameMain+could+be+accessed+at+s.send%22 and didn't see an existing one with the same error code.